# Приложение крашиться при запуске из BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android-studio

Вот код автозапуска службы. Код срабатывает видно по логам. Но приложение крашиться. Ссылается на строчку `Intent myService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);. Сразу скажу стоял андроид 7.х.х все работало перепрошился на 8.1.1. Появилась такая проблема. Если запустить службу при нажатии кнопки из активити, то проблем нет!

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {


            Intent myService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
             context.startService(myService);
    }
}
```

Comment: а логи можно увидеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Android O` поменялись правила для сервисов. В вашем случае вы пытаетесь открыть сервис при незапущенной актвиити. Так теперь нельзя на `API>26`. Вам надо стартовать сервис с показом уведомления как-то так:

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService()
```

или не использовать сервис вовсе и использовать что-то вроде `JobScheduler`.

Вот полезные статьи: [How to handle background services in ANDROID O?](https://medium.com/exploring-code/how-to-handle-background-services-in-android-o-f96783e65268) и [Exploring Background Execution Limits on Android Oreo](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-background-execution-limits-on-android-oreo-ab384762a66c)